# Retrieving POST data using Java

Tags: java, http-post

I'm trying to make a Java server that can accept and return data using POST. So far I have been trying to use nameValuePairs (although another method be fine) and have the server accepting connections, and accepting the HTTP header, but from here I cannot fathom how to get any attached data. The following code prints out the header and sends a 100 response once the client expects it - but how do I get the data from the message?

```
        while(true){
        inputLine = clientInput.readLine();
        System.out.println("client-msg: " + inputLine);
        if("Expect:".equals(inputLine.split(" ")[0])){
            sendResponse(100, "Continue");
            break;
        }
```

Here is what the (android java) client is sending, I'm looking to get the name pair out on the server side

```
            ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParams = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        postParams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("field", "data here"));
        UrlEncodedFormEntity uefe = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(
                postParams);
        request.setEntity(uefe);
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
```

This is probably fairly simple but I couldn't seem to find any non PHP tutorials for POST.

Comment: since Java 6 Java comes with an HTTP server (that is: no need to embed Jetty).  If you're after a really lightweight HTTP server, you may want to google for NanoHTTPD.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really need to do this by hand you should read the [HTTP RFC](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616.html) because it is potentially even more complicated than what you are trying to do now. If what you really want is a way to embed a small Java web server into something check out [Jetty](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/). It is really easy to [embed Jetty](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Tutorial/Embedding_Jetty) into other apps.

It should be as easy as:

```
public class SimpleServletContext
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        Server server = new Server(8080);

        ServletContextHandler context = new ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);
        context.setContextPath("/");
        server.setHandler(context);

        context.addServlet(new ServletHolder(new PostServlet()),"/*");

        server.start();
        server.join();
    }
}

public class PostServlet extends HttpServlet
{
    public PostServlet()
    { 
    }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        // do something with the posted data
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks carson, I would prefer this to be done myself (it doesn't need to be versatile or do anything other than receive the data and send something else back). As far as i'm aware after I send the 100- continue, the client sends the pair, although the BufferedReader, clientInput will return null at this point if I call readLine()

Comment: Didn't know about using servlets for this before, I'll give that a shot and get back with the results.

Comment: The biggest problem is if you get it working it could break again if you don't have control of the client. If you have control of the client you should probably not use HTTP but instead use straight sockets if you want to do it all by hand.

Answer (score 1):

From your code my understanding is that your approach is to open a server socket and read-in line by line.
What you are supposed to do here is find the header "Content-length".
This header shows the size of the body carried in the POST request.
From your question, I think that you are receiving a POST request similar to the following:

```
POST /path HTTP/1.1
From: myUser
User-Agent: java
Content-Length: 32

name1=value1&name2=value2
```

Note the extra new line (i.e. `'\n'`) between the HTTP headers and the actual data.
You should use the content length and the fact that you already know where are the data related to the HTTP headers, inside the HTTP request to parse it and extract the values of interest.
So that you eventually get the `name1=value1&name2=value2`.
If you just want to do it as an exercise, go ahead.
It is more complex than you think and you have to look to the RFC a bit.
For example I do not remember it is actually a `'\n'` or a `'\r\n'` or something similar.
Also I do not remember if content-length will be always there (for example in the responses it can be missing and the http server may send the response in encoded chunks).
If you need to do it though seriously, then you should use an http server implementation.
There is already an http server implementation shipped in java or you can use apache's.
Do not try to re-invent the wheel, unless you are doing for education or fun.

Comment: yea that's what I'm trying to do, I have extracted the content length but wasn't sure how to / or what to parse with it. You were correct that there is a newline between the last message but after this the socket appears closed!?

client-msg: Content-Length: 17
client-msg: Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
client-msg: Host: 192.168.1.144:5000
client-msg: Connection: Keep-Alive
client-msg: User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/UNAVAILABLE (java 1.4)
client-msg: Expect: 100-Continue
100 Response Sent
client-msg: 
java.net.SocketException: socket closed

Comment: @Smoo:You break the while loop (according to code in your OP) once you find the `Expect`. So you stop reading.So then how are you getting the exception?What you should do is i)get the content-length header ii) find the new line character. After that starts the content body.Keep reading from stream as much as content-length indicates. Parse content to get the name-value pairs

Comment: I should have mentioned I changed the code so that it didn't stop at expect but after the newline it throws the exception that the socket is closed. I've just used straight objects over sockets now though

Comment: @Smoo:It's hard to tell from your post why you get the exception.Are you closing the output stream on the client side?If you do that the underlying socket linked to the stream will be closed as well.

Answer (score 0):

From context, it looks as though you should look into using Servlets, and run it on a lightweight servlet platform like Jetty.

You must override the doPost method on the Servlet class. On the [HttpServletResponse](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/1.2.1/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html) object, use getParameterNames() to get all of the uploaded parameter names, and getParameter() to get their values.

Comment: Thanks for the answer nrobey, I should have explained though that it is a regular Java server, I am reading the client response using a BufferedReader (clientInput in the code) but this could well be the wrong way to go about it.